# Javascript Confirm Message on List on the server

Tags: java, javascript, jsf

I have a List of employees on the backing bean , I want to loop on this list and display a javascript confirm message(yes/no) for each employee..

assume the employee class has id , name , salary attributes
I want to display confirmation message
(Are you sure to save employee with id= , name= ,salary =) for each employee..
I need to know how to do this

It is not an actual use case that is a simple assumption because the actual one is complex to illustrate , just I need to Know the concept to do this..

Thanks In Advance

Comment: This is very user unfriendly. What if there are 100 employees? Do you really want to display 100 confirmation dialogues? Rather show it in a table with a single confirm button at bottom. It's after all also much easier to code.

Comment: It is not an actual case that is a simple case because the actual one is complex to illustrate , just I need to Know the concept to do this.. thanks for your consideration

Answer (score 1):

How about something similar to this:

```
for (i=0;i<employeeList.size;i++)
{
      alert([insert your data here]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how to read the list of data from the backing bean and display them on the javascript message